# Running selenium tests from Jenkins - cannot find firefox

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have some selenium tests written in java and built using maven. The pom file includes the jbehave and selenium libraries. It uses firefox browser. So I installed firefox on linux and included the path in my .bashrc. If I do a mvn clean install manually , it works fine.

But if I try the same thing using Jenkins ( am trying to automate the tests), it is throwing errors:

```
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] null
Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
```

I tried doing an echo of PATH within Jenkins and it did not show the path of firefox. So I also did an export PATH with the new path of firefox included and then called mvn clean install in Jenkins. Even though the PATH now showed the path of firefox in jenkins console output, it still throws the same error.

What is that I am missing?

Comment: What machine(linux/windows) do you have jenkins installed? If linux, do you have xvfb/xvnc running?

Comment: would you mind check your firefox installation via command `which firefox`? it should be `/usr/bin/firefox`, or you need to append your firefox path to the environment variable PATH. for example: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @amey: I run this on centos. I do not have xvfb/xvnc running. I dont need them. Please note that I am able to run this thru mvn clean install command manually. I am just not able to do this through Jenkins.

Comment: @shwanzhu:I have installed firefox in my home dir. I also did an export PATH=$PATH:/path/of/home/dir/firefox in my .bashrc

Comment: I reinstalled firefox in /usr/bin and it solved the problem. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

Three things to check:

1) as @shawnzhu said, check whether you have installed firefox properly?

2) To provide Binary path to your driver, you need to set system property. Use below code for selenium with java:

```
File firefoxPathBinary = new File("path/to/your//firefox-bin");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefoxPathBinary.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

3) For Ubuntu, path to your firefox executable could be - `usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin` and for Mac it could be `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to link the executable:

sudo unlink /usr/bin/firefox
sudo ln -s /path/to/new/firefox/executable /usr/bin/firefox